# Series expansion of sech term disappears

Tags: series-expansion

Came across this today, which looks like a bug to me. 
If I take the Series expansion which includes a numerical $\textrm{sech}^2(x)$ term that does not depend on the parameter, it fails to expand properly:

```
Series[Sech[100 (0.5 - x)]^2 ϵ, {ϵ, 0, 1}]

(* 0 *)
```

but the obvious answer should be `Sech[100 (0.5 - x)]^2 ϵ + O[ϵ^2]`. The machine precision is the issue here, if I use `1/2` instead it works fine.

Can anyone confirm if this is a bug.

Comment: Same with 11.2 on Win 7.

Comment: Thanks @b.gatessucks.  I have tested it myself on 9.0, 11.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: Same with 11.2 @ win 10. Though, if you add `Series[Sech[100 (N[1/2, 1] - x)]^2 ϵ, {ϵ, 0, 1}]` it expands properly.

Comment: Also if you decrease 100 down to ~60 or so it suddenly works fine.

Comment: It is due to this: `In[1]:= PossibleZeroQ[Sech[100 (0.5 - x)]^2]                                    

Out[1]= True` I would surmise this comes about from internals of zero testing doing some expansion and being unable to tell the machine arithmetic results fro zero. Does not happen when .5 is replaced with 1/2 or with a bignum approximate value e.g. 0.5`10 so this is an interaction between machine arithmetic and symbolic computation. I should note that this in and of itself is not regarded as a bug, at least not by me.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, looks pretty buggy to me. It was certainly unexpected behaviour when it occurred in the middle of a routine. Incidentally, `PossibleZeroQ[Sech[100 (0.5 - a)]^2 /. a -> Range[-100, 100, 1]]` gives a whole string of False, even though they are extremely small at the ends.

Comment: It is easier to do zero testing on explicitly numeric values than symbolic/numeric expressions. In the latter case, adding machine arithmetic to the mix is a recipe for bad outcomes.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, this feels like a bug to me. I don't really understand what is going on under the hood with machine precision, and why setting the precision lower actually makes it work.